# Java Linked List lookup framework

Tags: java, linked-list

I have two JAVA classes User and Users. Users is the main class which will list the instances of the User Class in a Linked List. user should be able to add and delete users. My coe is not doing the deleting.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Users {

// Main method
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Users();
}
//attributes
private LinkedList<User> users = new LinkedList<User>();

//Constructors
public Users(){
    add();
    add(); 
}

//Methods

//adds a user to the list
private void add(){
    users.add(new User());
}
//deletes a user from the list
private void delete(){
    User user = user(readName());
    if (user != null)
        users.remove(user);
    else
        System.out.println("    No such user");
}
 //returns the user if the user exists in the list
private User user(String name){
    for (User user: users)
        if (user.matches(name)){
            return user;
        }
    return null;

}
private String readName(){
    System.out.print("  Names: ");
    return In.nextLine();
}

}


User class

public class User {

//Attributes
private String name;
private Users users;

//Constructors
public User(){
    this.name = readName();
}

//Methods
//checks if the parameter is equal to the name field
public boolean matches(String name){
    return this.name == name;
}
public void add(){
    System.out.print(" " + name);
}
public void delete(){

}
public String readName(){
    System.out.print("  Name: ");
    return In.nextLine();
}

}
```

In the Users class the `user(String s)` method is not delivering the element, even if it was added to the list. 
please some advices

Answer (score 0):

Your delete method needs the user object that you want to delete to be passed in as an argument. Currently you're declaring a new user object that doesn't contain any information about the user you want deleted except you're prompting for the name of the user. You should pass the user object into the delete method so it looks something like this.

```
//deletes a user from the list
private void delete(User user) {
    if (user != null) 
        users.remove(user);
    else
        System.out.println("     No such user");
}
```